# Is there a terminal commands cheat sheet application?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I stumbled upon a terminal cheat sheet [here](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/CliCommandsFull.jpg) and I started wondering if there was anyway to display this in Ubuntu 12.04, much in the way that holding the [Super] key displays tips for window managing and shortcuts.

Is there any app or desklet or something that provides this effect? I'm very new to Linux and this quick reference would be very useful to me.

Comment: Why don't you just save that image on your Desktop and open it whenever you want to take a look?

Comment: That would be one way of doing it, but I was wondering if I could simply map a keyboard shortcut to it or something.

Comment: I managed to do it with Compiz/Shortcuts to run `shotwell filename.jpg` but it looks kinda clunky. It serves it's purpose, but I wondered if there was a _cleaner_ alternative...

Comment: Not really, not if you want to display that image at least. There may be an app for this but I doubt it. Not much point in it really since you can always just open an image or equivalent.

Comment: The image was to illustrate what I meant. The effect I'm looking for is displaying something like Unity's Desktop Shortcuts overlay.

Comment: set the image as your wallpaper?

Answer (score 3):

Not quite what you are looking for, but `cheat.sh` is a very nice thing. This is an universal cheat sheet for almost anything, not only Linux terminal commands but also many programming languages etc.

It works online by accessing the webpage which is under this very address [cheat.sh](http://cheat.sh). You can use it right from the browser, but the preferred way is to install `curl` (`sudo apt install curl`) and then running the following command in terminal:

```
curl cheat.sh
```

It will explain how to use it and use more commands.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution to looking at an image to learn text commands is to use `apropos` with a search term. `apropos permissions`, `apropos disk`, `apropos network`, `apropos search` &c